# Prolog - Checking 2x2 cells in a list of lists

Tags: prolog

Basically I am trying to implement a program in **prolog** that can solve a game called **Yin Yang**, independente of the size of the board.
The game is basically to paint every cell of the board of a specific color (either black or white) and all cells of same color are connected to each other, vertically or horizontally. I am representing this with a list of lists. Example initial->solution: https://i.gyazo.com/24a70d868934dfbf1540343e89d14c4b.png

However there is a rule I'm having trouble with: **"No 2X2 group of cells can contain circles of a single color."**

Any ideas how I can assure this doesn't happen using the clpfd library?

List  representing board example:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,2,0],
 [0,2,0,0,2,2],
 [1,0,2,0,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1]]
```

Comment: do you have any code written?

Comment: @aimee yes, but not for this rule in specific. Just other board restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue: This is the code I used for solving the problem described above.

```
twoByTwo([_],[_]). 
twoByTwo([F1,S1|T1],[F2,S2|T2]):-
   F1 + S1 + F2 + S2 #> 4,
   F1 + S1 + F2 + S2 #< 8,
   twoByTwo([S1|T1],[S2|T2]).
```

Basically twoByTwo receives a line of the board (in order) on each argument.

So basically this function is called recursively: twoByTwo(Line1,Line2), twoByTwo(Line2,Line3), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do a variant of the problem :

```
get-elem(B, R, C, E) :- get-line(B, R, Row), get-line(Row, C, E).

get-line([R|_], 0, R).
get-line([_|A], N, R) :- get-line(A, M, R), N is M + 1.

twoXTwo(B, R, C) :- \+ (R1 is R+ 1, C1 is C+1,
                        get-elem(B, R, C, E1),  
                        get-elem(B, R1, C, E2),  E1 = E2,
                        get-elem(B, R, C1, E3),  E2 = E3, 
                        get-elem(B, R1, C1, E4), E3 = E4).
```

where I check the element at positions `[(r+1,c), (r,c+1), (r+1,c+1)]` are not the same element. I am also not sure what the numbers mean given you have either black (1) or white (0).

Comment: First of all `s/-/_/`

Comment: The 0 stands for empty cell, 1 stands for white pieces and 2 for black. 
In the end there should be no 0s, those are just for the original input (semi filled board to be completed according to the game rules)